# TableView not displaying parsed data from xml?

Tags: iphone

i have tabbar controller, first tab is for Tableview controller.but i do xml parsing in appldidfinish method , in the xml parse `didEndElement`, i calculate items count and i give
it into  first tab's Tableview controller's `numberOfRowsInSection`,but after xml parsing finished, the following method wont be called. tableview is empty....?

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
   return [myParser.items count];
}
```

i have declared in view did load method of that table view controller

```
myParser = [[XMLMyParser alloc] init];
```

any help please.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [tableview has nothing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715283/tableview-has-nothing)

Answer (score 1):

When the XML parsing is complete, you need to inform the table view that the data has changed.
You do this by sending the reloadData message to your table view instance:

```
[myTableView reloadData];
```

Assuming you're using the NSXMLParser, you will need to add this in parserDidEndDocument message of your NSXMLParserDelegate implementation