# tableview has nothing?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

my tableview has the following method.i have done everything perfectly...`numberOfRowsInSection` `returns 10`.....the following method will not be called....it shows nothing......

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of places you could have gone wrong...and if you post some code you're much more likely to get a solution but some possibilities.

Have you also implemented

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

Have you set the tableview's datasource and delegate to your controller? (Either programatically or via interface builder outlets)

Does your controller declare the UITable view datasource and delegate protocols in it's header OR subclass UITableViewController?

Without you providing more info it's pretty hard to give a solution.

Comment: I'm very new to iPad development and missed the dataSource and Delegate connectors so your comment helped me :) Thanks.